# After impersonation authentication screen keeps popping up in my ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, popup, impersonation

I'm working on a program that has to archive (zip and delete files and folders) on a server. The servers that hosts the application (ASP.NET MVC) and the server that holds the files are two different servers. When I run the application without impersonation and the default web configuration everything works fine. The credential of the program is: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. When I use impersonation by adding the following line in the web.config `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` the program runs fine with anonymous login. When I prevent anonymous login by adding the following code to the web.config, the authentication screen keeps popping up for every folder or file I want to access.

What's the problem?

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work, you need to disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows Authentication in IIS, otherwise it doesn't have an identity to impersonate being passed.

[Here's how to do that :)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/524404dc-8586-46b0-89ac-0f5db6d33c9c.mspx?mfr=true)